# wdt on pic with c get errors

Tags: c, pic, mplab, watchdog

I have this:

```
static void ButtonDebounce(void)
{    
static uint16_t debounceCounter = 0;
// Check if only one S3 or s4 button pressed since if I have bouncing several
// interrupts will occur and will result on several resets on board.

if ((BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S3 ) == true) || (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S4 ) == true)){
    if(debounceCounter == 0)
    {
        LED_Toggle( LED_D4 ); //Led blinks when Btn3 or Btns4 is pressed.
        if (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S3 ) == true){
            //__asm__ volatile ("reset"); // soft-reset not recommended.
      
            RCONBITS.SWDTEN = 1; // Software Enable of WDT => page 99 PIC24FJ1024GA610/GB610 documentation
                                // #pragma config WDT = ON. => Page 43 - MPLAB_XC16_C_Compiler_Users_Guide.pdf
                                // Enable WDT. The safer way to implement 
                                // reset on the system is via WDT since this 
                                // timer is resetting the whole
                                // board and not only the Microcontroller.
                                                   
            while(1){} // Just wait for wdt to reset the system.
        }
        else if (BUTTON_IsPressed( BUTTON_S4 ) == true){
            printf("Avg Temp = %4f\r\n Avg Hmdt = %4f\r\n Min Temp = %4d\r\n Max Temp = %4d\r\n Min Hmdt = %4d\r\n Max Hmdt = %4d\r\n", 
                    calculateAvgTemp(), calculateAvgHumidity(), calculateMinTemp(), 
                    calcuateMaxTemp(), calculateMinHumidity(), calcuateMaxHumidity());
        }
    }        
    debounceCounter = BUTTON_DEBOUCE_TIME_MS;
} else{
    if(debounceCounter != 0)
    {
        debounceCounter--;
    }
   }
}
```

and getting that:

```
main.c: In function 'ButtonDebounce':
main.c:123:25: error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
make[2]: *** [build/default/debug/main.o] Error 255
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:135: recipe for target 'build/default/debug/main.o' failed
```

Any suggestion? I tried to implement everything as documentation says: PIC24FJ1024GB610, I have many years to be involved with pic and then I was with assembly. The problem is on RCONBITS.SWDTEN = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Change `RCONBITS.SWDTEN = 1;` to `RCONbits.SWDTEN = 1;` this may resolve the error.